# Let $ L = \infty $ and $ M\neq \infty $ Show that $ \lim_{n \to \infty }(x_n + y_n) = L + M$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, proof-writing

$L$ and $M$ are the limits of the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ respectively

I have already proven for the case where $L,M \in \mathbb{R}$.

The method I used doesn't work here where the absolute value contains a limit of $ \infty$. So I can't use the standard definition of a Limit. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: I suppose $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = L$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}y_n = M$ and $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are sequences?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. $L$ and $M$ are the limits of the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ respectively

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\lim_n x_n=+\infty$, $\lim_n y_n=M\neq\infty$. 
Thus for $\epsilon=1$ there exists $m$ such that
$$(\forall n\geq m)\ |y_n-M|<\epsilon=1. $$
$\lim_n x_n=+\infty$ gives for any $N$
there exists $n_0$ such that 
$$(\forall n\geq n_0)\ x_n\geq N. $$
Thus for any $n\geq \max\{n_0,m\}$ you have $x_n+y_n \geq N-M-1$.

Case $\lim_n x_n=-\infty$ is symmetric.